# How do I speed up IntelliJ IDEA's File/Directory Select Dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea

I started up IntelliJ IDEA and wanted to create a new project from existing sources. The first thing that popped up was the directory selector dialog window. It took almost 10 minutes to load directories, locking up the rest of the IDE in the meantime.

What can I do to make that not happen?

Comment: Do you have any network drives connected?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101218) for that:

> **Problem**: when a file chooser is opened for, say, "/home/user" start
>   path, it's file system tree component expands all intermediate
>   directory nodes and so loads all their children. This may block
>   indefinitely if a file system contains "black holes" (e.g.
>   **network-mounted directory** under /home which is inaccessible at the
>   moment).
>
> **Goal**: redesign the dialog by eliminating the tree and so avoid loading
>   all children for directories which are higher than start path in a FS
>   tree.

It may help if you set the default project directory so that this dialog doesn't open at the root of the network mount home or try to access some slow network drive:

[image: default directory]